# I want to send a NSMutableDictionary from the iPhone to a server

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I have a NSMutableDictionary and I want to send it to a URL as an XML file. I want the XML file to be stored in a folder on the URL.

I have found through googling stuff that I can "serealize" the NSMutableDictionary. Here is how I did it:

```
NSString *error;
self.rootSerialDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

[self convertDrinkArrayToDictionary];
[self.rootSerialDict setObject:self.drinkSerialDic forKey:@"Drinks"];
[self convertSpecialsArrayToDictionary];
[self.rootSerialDict setObject:self.specialsSerialDic forKey:@"Specials"];  
[self convertCustomerInfoToDictionary];
[self.rootSerialDict setObject:self.customerInfoSerialDict forKey:@"CustomerInfo"];
[self convertLocationInfoToDictionary];
[self.rootSerialDict setObject:self.locationInfoSerialDict forKey:@"Location"];
[self createDictionaryOfMiscItems];
[self.rootSerialDict setObject:self.miscItemSerialDict forKey:@"MiscTotals"];

//convert the root serial dictionary to a XML plist
id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization 
dataFromPropertyList:(id)self.rootSerialDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
```

This "serealizes" the dictionary. Do I have to send this serealized object to the URL or can I convert this serealized object into an XML file and then send that XML file to the URL?

Right now I donot have a PHP script on the server that can parse the XML file. But I just want the XML file to reside on the URL.
Can I do this? 
Can I use the NSURLConnection POST method to do that or will I have to use some other way like ftp?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert the `NSDictionary` to json using:

[json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)

And then I would send the json to your webserver using:

[AsiHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

It would be much easier on both ends to deal with json.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I would prefer XML at the moment as Im not familiar at all with json.

Comment: Could someone please help me with the above question. How can I convert my dictionary to a XML file that can be sent to a URL?

Comment: Well, personally I think you're making a mistake by avoiding json, xml is *harder*. Try this xml for android tutorial:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/